# Ошибка NullPointerException в сервисе

Tags: android

Есть сервис в котором проигрывается радио и активити откуда в сервис передается url и название радио. В маркете за последние пару дней обнаружил что у пользователей выходит ошибка NullPointerException.

NullPointer в этой строчке

```
stream = intent.getStringExtra("stream");
```

Проверял на рабочих устройствах, на виртуальном устройстве. При тестировании у меня не возникало такого случая У меня не возникало. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно оптимизировать мой код? Что я не так сделал

Вот что там пишут

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at ru.myapps.onlineradio.PlayerService.onStartCommand (PlayerService.java:59)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:2854)
```

Вот активити с которого отправляются данные в сервис

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private String stream;
    private String radio;
    private int img;

    static boolean isPlay = false;
    static ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;
    private CircleImageView imgRadio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
        imgRadio = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRadio);

        stream = getIntent().getStringExtra("stream").trim();
        radio = getIntent().getStringExtra("radio").trim();
        img = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("img");

        setTitle(radio);
        txtRadio.setText(radio);
        imgRadio.setImageResource(img);

        startPlayerService();

    }

    public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("stream", stream);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("radio", radio);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("img", img);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = true;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
    }

    private void stopPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = false;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
    }


    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (isPlay) {
            stopPlayerService();
        } else {
            startPlayerService();
        }
    }

}
```

Вот сам сервис

```
public class PlayerService extends IntentService {
    public static Context context;
    boolean isPlay = false;
    String stream;
    String radio;
    int img;
    Notification notification;

    final String myLog = "LOG";

    public PlayerService() {
        super("PlayerService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    }

    private void showNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Играет: " + radio)
                .setContentText("Открыть список радиостанций")
                .setSmallIcon(img)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context = this;
        stream = intent.getStringExtra("stream");
        radio = intent.getStringExtra("radio");
        img = intent.getIntExtra("img", 0);

        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = true;
            showNotification();
            RadioPlayer.startPlayer(stream, this);
        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
            stopForeground(true);
            Player.btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            Player.isPlay = false;
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вижу как минимум 2 системные ошибки:

1. `Service` вызывается у вас при создании `Activity` - не совсем кошерно, но вполне допустимо, если только вы не останавливаете службу в `onDestroy()` - чего у вас как раз и нет - соответственно, при повторном запуске `Activity`, например при примитивном повороте устройства, вы запустите службу второй раз, а поскольку служба ранее уже была запущена с флагом `START_STICKY`, то `Intent` будет равен `null` (надо запускать с флагом `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`) - [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_FLAG_REDELIVERY)
2. `Service` выполняется в основном потоке, поэтому крайне рекомендуется сажать тело сервиса в `Runnable/Thread` - у вас этого также нет. Проще всего вместо `Service` таки использовать `IntentService` - он в отличие от `Service` выполняется в отдельном потоке + при повторном запуске, он создает очередь

Comment: Обновил в вопросе код сервиса. Так имеете ввиду сделать?

Comment: А про остановку службу при закрытии Активити. Как быть если я не хочу чтобы сервис останавливался при закрытии Player активити

Comment: И еще такой вопрос. Обязательно ли в методе onHandleIntent получать данные переданные из Player актвити или это можно оставить как есть (т.е. получать в методе onStartCommand)?

Comment: Вы так и будете исторгать из себя новые каменты каждую минуту? :)

Comment: нет, я смотрел примеры где используется IntentService  и в них в методе onHandleIntent  получают данные через intent, если я так делаю то у меня потом в методе onStartCommand ошибка возникает. то ли stream переменная оказывается пустой то ли что-то еще. С телефона пишу нет возможности лог посмотреть сейчас. Но ругается на строки где я в onStartCommand использую stream и radio